# MS Access VBA Valor digitado en txtbox1 debe mostrar valores en txtbox2 y txtbox3

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

En MS Access 2016, la tbl01 tiene tres campos: std_Id, stdnomb y std_nota.
Tengo un formulario basado en tbl01 y tiene txtid, txtnombre y txtnota.
He estado tratando de escribir un código para lo siguiente:
Al es[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]cribir un valor en la txtid, el código debe mostrar los valores asociados en la txtnombre y la txtnota (ver imagen adjunta).

De manera preliminar, he probado este código, pero, no funciona:

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Sub txtid_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtid.Value = Me.txtnombre
    Me.txtid.Value = Me.txtnota
End Sub
```

Bienvenidas las sugerencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto, puedes usar DLookUp.

Prueba así:

```
Sub txtid_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtnombre.Value = DLookUp("[stdnomb]","tbl01","[std_Id]=" & Me.txtid.Value
    Me.txtnota.Value = DLookUp("[std_nota]","tbl01","[std_Id]=" & Me.txtid.Value
End Sub
```

Pero si los 3 campos están en la misma tabla, creo que sería mucho más fácil simplemente crearse un formulario basado en la tabla `tbl01` e insertarse los campos que quieres ver. Así aparecería toda la información ya relacionada, sin usar código VBA.

Comment: Con el Intellisense escribí el primer código y las letras se colorearon de rojo. 
Ante ello, coloqué un paréntesis al final y las letras perdieron ese color.
Luego, en el formulario, en txtid escribí un valor de la tbl01, seguido coloqué el cursor en 'txtnombre' que mostró un valor (strint) de la tbl01. .
Para la segunda procedí similar.
En el formulario en 'txtid' escribí un valor, coloqué el cursor en  'txtnota' y ocurre 'Error 2471' La expresion que ha especificado como parámetro de la consulta produjo el error '[std_nota]'
Ver siguiente mensaje.

Comment: Veo que 'std_nota' es numérico, por ello, lo escribo así:
'Me.txtnota.Value = DLookup([std_nota], "tbl01", "[std_Id]=" & Me.txtid.Value)'
Pero 'txt_nota' muestra valor = 0 'sin error
Aun no tengo instruccion para que muestre el valor en 'txt_nota'. Sugerencias bienvenidas.

El formulario basado en tbl01 es para ingresar nuevos registros.

Comment: Finalmente, pude escribir los códigos para usar la Función DLookUp, incluso agregué otra búsqueda.
Este es el código para las tres búsquedas con DLookUp. 
'Private Sub stdcard_id_AfterUpdate()'
'std_id = DLookup("[std_id]", "[tbl01]", "std_id=" & std_id)'
'txtnombre = DLookup("[stdnomb]", "[tbl01]", "stdcard_id=" & stdcard_id)'
'txtnota = DLookup("[stdnota]", "[tbl01]", "stdcard_id=" & stdcard_id)'
'End Sub'
Aprecio su invitación a investigar para hallar soluciones.